# Adding data between components Angular

Tags: angular, service, components

So I have this form on createcourse that I can add a new course in the CourseList component. The first problem is that everytime I add a new course the header of the table duplicates also. But I want to add any course that will appear in the CourseList(with the "Choose" button) in a new list in the myCourse component. Here's the code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-scw6yc

Answer (score -1):

The table header is duplicated as you mistakenly put table head in course list item component rather than in courselist component before the ngfor

Comment: How can I add the table head in the courseList when its a div class

Comment: You need to create table component in the courselist and just loop over the tr element,  then you dont even need to create new component

Comment: Im not really understanding what u trying to say

Comment: Just add table as you added in the item component,  in place of the app-item component and then when using tr make it in ngFor to repeat the row

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-scw6yc?file=course-list%2Fcourse-list.component.html
???

Comment: <tbody>
     <tr  *ngFor="let courseEl of courses$ | async" >
            <td style="width: 10px">{{courseEl.code}}</td>
            <td style="width: 75px">{{courseEl.name}}</td>
            <td style="width: 10px">{{courseEl.ects}}</td>
            <td style="width: 75px">{{courseEl.lekt}}</td>
          <td id="button1"> <button type="button" (click)="getData()" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-sm m-0">Choose</button></td>
        </tr>
    
  </tbody>